# Crear un combobox desde modelo con Entity Framework ASP NET CORE MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Buen día, estoy creando un proyecto web (soy nuevo en net core mvc) y tengo mi modelo ya creado y funcionando. El problema es que cuando genero la vistas con Scaffolding en visual studio 2017 en base al modelo, crea las vistas con todos los campos que le dije en el modelo pero todo lo genera como etiquetas input de tipo texto, es decír, como textbox. Hay unos campos que me gustaría generarlos ya con opciones en un combobox (select con sus options), sin embargo, no sé que anotación de EF o tipo de dato tendría que elegir en el modelo para lograr que aparezcan así con las opciones ya escritas desde el modelo.

Entonces este sería el modelo de mi clase usuario:

```
public class usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int usuarioID { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Nombre de la persona")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Apellido de la persona")]
    public string apellido { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Nombre de usuario")]
    public string codusuario { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Password")]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Estado del usuario")]
    public string estado { get; set; }

    [Display (Name = "Fecha")]
    public DateTime fechacreacion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
    public int empresa { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Rol")]
    public string rol { get; set; }

}
```

Por poner un ejemplo, el campo que será el "estado" quisiera que al generar con scaffolding la vista, me aparezca con un select que tenga las opciones "activo" e "inactivo", por poner un ejemplo. Pero no sé qué anotación debería escribir para ponerle esos valores y que salga como un select en la vista al generarlo. Ya que si solo lo pongo así como está, lo genera como un input de tipo text. Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr eso necesitas tener otra entidad (Tabla) Estados, de esa forma se te va generar un ComboBox.
La forma mas sencilla seria:

```
public class Usuario
{
        [Key]
        public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Nombre de la persona")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Apellido de la persona")]
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
            
        [Display (Name = "Nombre de usuario")]
        public string Codusuario { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public int EstadoId { get; set; }
        [Display (Name = "Estado del usuario")]
        public Estado Estado { get; set; }

        [Display (Name = "Fecha")]
        public DateTime Fechacreacion { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Empresa")]
        public int Empresa { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Rol")]
        public string Rol { get; set; }

}

public class Estado
{
     public int EstadoId { get; set; }
     public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Te recomiendo que respetes las convenciones de EF, para que todo te funcione correctamente. Como por ejemplo Nombrar de forma correcta las propiedades (UsuarioId), de esta manera EF reconoce esta propiedad como la llave primaria.

Comment: ohhh, muchas gracias entonces así lo haré